# Java primitives and overloading

Tags: java, overloading, primitive-types

I have always heard (and thought of) Java as a strongly typed language. But only recently did I notice something that I have been using almost on a daily basis: `int` and `double` overloading.

I can write the following, and it is valid Java code:

```
int i = 1;
double j = 1.5;
double k = i + j;
```

But, if I have a method, one of whose arguments is a `double`, I need to specify it:

```
public static <K, V> V getOrDefault(K k, Map<K, V> fromMap, V defaultvalue) {
    V v = fromMap.get(k);
    return (v == null) ? defaultvalue : v;
}
```

When I call the above method on a `Map<String, Double>`, the `defaultvalue` argument cannot be an `int`:

```
getOrDefault(aString, aStringDoubleMap, 0); // won't compile
getOrDefault(aString, aStringDoubleMap, 0d); // compiles and runs just fine
```

Why does Java overload an `int` to `double` (just like it does in addition), and then autobox it to `Double`? I think the answer lies in how Java does operator overloading (i.e. the overloading happens in the `+` operator, and not from `int` to `double`), but I am not sure.

Here's hoping that SO can help me out on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because primitives don't work with generics. They need to be boxed.

For the invocation

```
getOrDefault(aString, aStringDoubleMap, 0); // won't compile
```

to work, Java would have to box the `0` to an `Integer`, then somehow convert that to a `Double`. That's not allowed by the language.  It's similar to why you can't do

```
Double value = 3; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Double
```

From the JLS, [on invocation contexts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)

> If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the
>   parameter by a conversion permitted in a loose invocation context,
>   then a compile-time error occurs.

The type of the expression, `0`, an integer literal, is `int`. Loose invocation contexts are defined as

> Loose invocation contexts allow a more permissive set of conversions,
>   because they are only used for a particular invocation if no
>   applicable declaration can be found using strict invocation contexts.
>   Loose invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion

`int` to `Double` is not supported by any of those.

If you simply had

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    method(3);
}

public static void method(double d) {
}
```

it would work.

Comment: I see. I thought Java would *first* convert 0 to 0d (the widening conversion mentioned by Renjith and Andrew), and *then* autobox. Conversion from `Integer` to `Double` is not allowed, of course, as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [exciting section 5.2 of the Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Basically when you add an int and double it performs a widening conversion. But it doesn't know to do this when trying to Autobox an int to a Double. It's explicitly disallowed in fact.

Comment: This is covered by invocation contexts, not assignment contexts.

Comment: That is true it's section 5.3 not 5.2 but the list of conversions allowed is the same in both sections.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support operator overloading(An exception is String concat (+)) operator.

```
double k = i + j;
```

Here what is happening is implicit casting.A data type of lower size  is widened to a data type of higher size. This is done implicitly by the JVM.

And for `getOrDefault`, primitives wont work with generics.And here comes `autoboxing`.
When you call `getOrDefault(aString, aStringDoubleMap, 0d);`, the 0d will be autoboxed to Double object.
But JVM cannot autobox 0 to a Double object in your first case.

Java will not perform a widening primitive conversion (0 to 0d) and a boxing conversion (double to Double) implicitly.

Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

An implicit cast from int to double, followed by boxing to Double, is not allowed.

0 can be only autoboxed to Integer.
0d can be autoboxed to Double.

Answer (score -1):

The `int` -> `double` conversion is a widening conversion.  Widening conversions do not lose data, so they are [performed automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html).

Comment: That is not OP's question. The question is why in `Double d = 1;`, the literal `1` is not converted to `double` and then autoboxed into `Double`. And no, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: Maybe a typo in the question? Quoting: "Why does Java overload an int to double (just like it does in addition), and then autobox it to Double? "  I guess he meant "does not", but I missed that.